# Problems with hover CSS

Tags: html, css

I have problems with hover css.

Text in the class don't change the color when I hover on the picture but changes when traffic on the word.

I want to make the color change when the hover on the picture as well because the background of the picture is the same as the original font color.

### HTML

```
<li class="category-location">
    <div id="category-location-table">
        <div class="category-location-row">
            <div class="category-location-description">
                <h3><a href="/admin">description</a></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

### CSS

```
ul.subcategories-location{
    float :right;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
ul.subcategories-location li{
    float :right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 230px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
ul.subcategories-location li h3 a{
    font-family: @fancyFont;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#category-location-table{
    color:#F7A51E;
    margin-left: 65px;
    background: url('design/img/category-itmes-1.png') no-repeat;
    height:60px;
    width:230px;
    display: table;
    display: table-row;
    float :right;
}   
#category-location-table a{
    color:#A20734;
}   
#category-location-table a:hover{
    color:#fff;
}   
#category-location-table :hover{
    background: url('design/img/category-itmes-2.png') no-repeat;
    height:60px;
    width:230px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

I hope this makes sense and somebody will be able to help.

Comment: you need to specify the item where you want the hover.  it works on your link because you have it specified with `a:hover`   there's nothing but a space before your second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it something **[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/syuzobdd/)**?

```
#category-location-table:hover .category-location-description a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo on the last line.  #category-location-table:hover not #category-location--table :hover.